# How to sum the values of two columns and have it in a new one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

I'm trying to sum the values of two columns into a new one, its for analysis purpose (not creating a new column in the database)
I tried using case statement but I have no idea what is happening :
***(Basically what I'm trying to say is: if the sum of the 2 columns is equal or grater than one, then count it as 1, if its 0 or null then skip and return zero)***
please see the attached pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include your current query.

Comment: sum(case when speciality_count + italian_count >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS twocount

Comment: What you want seems irrelevant with the provided data within the images.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, I want to sum the first two columns and represent the result in the third one, but the result are not accurate for some reason :)

Comment: Why does exist `twocount` ? Is the second image desired result? What's your current attempt to solve the problem? Btw, Can you please share the text data rather than images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the the sum of the two columns, you just need ton handle the null values properly.

```
SELECT COALESCE(speciality_count, 0) + COALESCE(Italian_count, 0)
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Still shows inaccurate numbers to me... ex. column 1 = 4 , column 2 = 26, result = 24

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you are  trying to add the values in the two columns, you do not even need a case statement.  You can simply add them after handling the nulls.

Comment: Yea you're right, it worked that way... I was afraid at first from the null values.  Thank you :)